# How to avoid nested foreach using PHP generator for MYSQL data to increase perfomance?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, yield

I have the following code

```
$this->connection->transactional(function () {
        $data = $this->connection->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM faq_questions')->fetchAll();
        $faqs = $this->connection->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM faq')->fetchAll();
        $countries = $this->connection->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM countries')->fetchAll();

        foreach ($faqs as $faq) {
            foreach ($countries as $country) {
                foreach ($data as $datum) {
                    if ($datum['faq_id'] === $faq['id']) {
                        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare('INSERT INTO faq_questions ...');
                        $stmt->execute([...]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

It works well. In order to save the memory my teamlead adviced me to refactor this code.
How can I avoid the third **foreach** using PHP generators?

Comment: It seems to me that you really need to be creating a query to do the whole job, not tinkering with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you can remove the loops with joins.

It's unclear you full SQL syntax, but this should point you in the right direction:

```
$query='
    select * 
    from faq
        left join faq_questions faq.id=faq_questions.faq_id
        left join countries=faq.countries.id=faq.countries_id
';

$questions=$this->connection->executeQuery($query)->fetchAll();

foreach($questions as $question){
    //do insert stuff
}
```

Note, this is untested and I don't know your correct schema, so you may need to change some things, but hopefully, it's enough to help.

Comment: it's possible you'll want `faq_questions` as the "primary" table not `faq`

Comment: Given the complete schema it should be possible to get rid of that last remaining loop, too.

Comment: Correct, unless there's some extra "magic" that needs to be done code side.